# How to error check urllib.request

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, urllib

I have a line in python code that reads:

```
req = urllib.request.urlopen(path + "robots.txt", data=None)
```

But this seems to be erroring out if the website.com/robots.txt doesn't exist. How can I add an error checking condition that just sets req to blank if this doesn't work instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good use case for a `try - except` block.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

try:
    req = urlopen(path + "robots.txt", data=None)
except HTTPError as e:
    # do something
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    # do something (set req to blank)
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by blank, but you can set it to whatever you want it inside of the except blocks, depending on what the error is. In your case, I believe you are getting a URLError, in which case you can do something like `req = None` (or whatever you'd like).